# Opening a text document with Windows Notepad

Tags: windows, notepad

Often (but not always) when I open a text file using Windows Notepad, it does not recognize the line breaks.

If I open the file using Windows Wordpad, and then save it as a text file, and then open it with Notepad, the line breaks are recognized.

What causes this, and what is the easiest way to view/edit the file using Notepad?

Comment: Notepad doesn't recognise carriage returns (CR), but only newlines (LF).

Comment: Actually Windows standard line breaks are CRLF and not just CR or LF.

Comment: [Interesting description](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/) that explains the history behind the conventions and why it causes problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by this phenomenon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Notepad only understands the windows newline format, so you will have to use another program. Notepad++ is quite popular on Windows (and opensource).  Notepad++ is also much better at handling large files.